# Non Blocking Server in Python

Tags: python, sockets, nonblocking

Can someone please tell how to write a Non-Blocking server code using the socket library alone.Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Frankly, just don't (unless it's for an exercise). The [Twisted Framework](http://twistedmatrix.com/) will do everything network-related for you, so you have to write only your protocol without caring about the transport layer. Writing socket code is not easy, so why not use code somebody else wrote and tested.

Comment: Indeed use twisted, I once wrote an event based socket library myself, it's a pain in the a... Even simple things like checking wether a connection was closed by the client or by an error can get you in a lot of trouble. It's definively only worth it if you want to learn a lot about how sockets work, but it's a lot of trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

Why `socket` alone? It's *so* much simpler to use another standard library module, `asyncore` -- and if you can't, at the **very** least `select`!

If you're constrained by your homework's condition to only use `socket`, then I hope you can at least add `threading` (or `multiprocessing`), otherwise you're *seriously* out of luck -- you can make sockets with `timeout`, but juggling timing-out sockets without the needed help from any of the other obvious standard library modules (to support either async **or** threaded serving) is a serious mess indeed-y...;-).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "socket library alone" - you surely will need other modules from the standard Python library.

The lowest level of non-blocking code is the [select module](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html). This allows you to have many simultaneous client connections, and reports which of them have input pending to process. So you select both the server (accept) socket, plus any client connections that you have already accepted. A thin layer on top of that is the asyncore module.

Answer (score 0):

Use eventlets or gevent. It monkey patches existing libraries. socket module can be used without any changes. Though code appears synchronous,  it executes asynchronously.

Example:
http://eventlet.net/doc/examples.html#socket-connect